# What are the variables describing in this equation?

Tags: dc-motor, math, rotor-speed

[image: Speed of a DC motor equation]
For my course, we have to use this formula when calculating the speed of a DC motor.
I know V, I, R and Φ, but i'm not totally sure what c, Z, p and K are.

I think p is number of poles in the motor.
I think Z is number of turns.
But I have no idea what C and K are.

Annoyingly there is no mention of this in the lecture notes so was probably described to us vocally.All other formulas on the internet use different values so i haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks a lot -- A very stressed Electronics student

Full formula sheet:
[image]

Comment: Where did you get this formula from? I am sure that source is fully describing each of these.

Comment: This is from the formula sheet given to us during the exams. It's only one page long and i can't find any explanation on it either.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the full formula sheet, so you can see what i'm working with here.

Comment: k is usually Kv, the motor's speed constant (radians/sec per volt)

Comment: I think Z is the number of conductors, c is the number of parallel paths for armature current, p may be pole pairs, and k = 2Zp/c from the Formula Sheet motor speed equation. You need to find the derivation given tor you to you to verify that. There are various ways to write the equations depending on whether you want to use poles or pole pairs, flux or flux per pole, radians per second, revolutions per second or revolutions per minute etc.